# Passing Stata loops onto R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, stata

**EDIT - Improved the question by including a reproducible example and giving more clarity to my issues**

Hi, my issue is that I have to translate this Stata code to R for it to be used in a large dataset:

```
sort UF UPA Ano Trimestre
            loc j = 1
            loc stop = 0 
            loc count = 0
            while `stop' == 0 {
                loc lastcount = `count'
                count if p201 == . & n_p == `i'+1 
                loc count = r(N)
                if `count' == `lastcount' {
                    loc stop = 1
                }
                else {
                    if r(N) != 0 {
                        replace p201 = p201[_n - `j'] if
        UF == UF[_n - `j'] &
        UPA == UPA[_n - `j'] &
        n_p == `i'+1 & n_p[_n - `j'] == `i' & 
        p201 ==. & forw[_n - `j'] != 1 &
        replace forw = 1 if UF == UF[_n + `j'] &
        UPA == UPA[_n + `j'] &
        p201 == p201[_n + `j'] &
        n_p == `i' & n_p[_n + `j']==`i'+ 1 &
        forw != 1
        loc j = `j' + 1
                    }
                    else {
                        loc stop = 1
                    }
                }
            }
            replace back = p201 !=. if n_p == `i'+1
            replace forw = 0 if forw != 1 & n_p == `i'
        }
```

My dataset is huge and more complex than the example posted below. I would like to understand mainly what is the usefulness of the `while` loop involving `j`.

Here is a toy example and the desired result in `R`:

```
start <- data.frame(
  Ano = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012),
  Trimestre = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  UF = c(28, 28, 28, 28),
  UPA = c(280020150, 280020150, 280020150, 280020150),
  n_p = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  p201 = c(1, NA, NA, NA),
  back = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
  forw = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

end <- data.frame(
  Ano = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012),
  Trimestre = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  UF = c(28, 28, 28, 28),
  UPA = c(280020150, 280020150, 280020150, 280020150),
  n_p = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  p201 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
  back = c(NA, 1, 1, 1),
  forw = c(1, 1, 1, 0)
)
```

Mainly, in the dataset there are multiple possible combinations for `UF`, `UPA` that identify the individual. `Ano` and `Trimestre` denote year and trimesters.

It seems as if the dataset is only matching all rows with the same `UF-UPA` by having them all according to the first value of `p201` in each group. Variables `back` and `forw` equal 1 if an observation is paired with some other one in a past or future date.

My question then is if someone can help me say what are the `while` and `j`'s for? I am not sure if the code could be greatly simplified in R by only using `group_by` from dplyr. I am not sure even if a `for` loop would be required.
However, I am not sure if this is only because of the particular subset of the data I have posted here or if these parts are indeed necessary. Is there a clever way to find out by testing some other stuff?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Just asking for code translation is off-topic. Say what the code needs to do and describe where exactly you are getting stuck during your translation.

Comment: I can't exactly do that, since I only have raw databases with and without running the whole code. Furthermore, I can't take a sample of it and paste it here

Comment: @MrFlick Please refer now to the updated question

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito In a [mcve] we may use sample data, _help: [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). You also need to focus on one problem to be on-topic. It's probably better to express what you want to do in R and show some attempts, rather than waiting for a translation from Stata to R.

Comment: @jay.sf The thing is that I've done exactly that in producing an exemple in R. I still think the Stata code is important since I am not sure the exemple I've posted is general enough - I dont get the part with the j subscripts and the while loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't read Stata code but from your text description it sounds like just a bit of `dplyr` will work for you

```
library(dplyr)
start %>% 
  group_by(UF, UPA) %>% 
  mutate(
    p201 = first(p201),
    back = row_number()>1,
    forw = row_number()<n()
  )
```

Comment: I've been ruminating for a while how to replicate SAS by group processing in R, and your answer to this question helped me figure it out. Upvoted.